# Issues editing credentials.yml Rails 6 on Windows 10 ubuntu Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, editor, atom-editor, credentials

I'm attempting to edit the credentials for an app in Rails 6 using ubuntu linux for windows 10. text editors used are atom and vs code(issue replicated in both). After I run the command below I get back an error. A credential file opens in my text editor, however,  It seems to be the wrong file and it is blank.

```
$ EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit
```

Error: grep: /etc/wsl.conf: No such file or directory

I've been able to gain access to the credentials file through git bash.. however, I rarely use git bash and I can't seem to figure out how to save changes after I edit and close the credentials.yml file. The Editor just seems to hang in my git bash console instead of closing automatically like with ubuntu. IS there a certain command to run after closing the file in my editor? (if I ctrl+C- git bash aborts and and nothing is saved).

I've searched through other stack overflow posts here but none of the similar answers seem to resolve my problem. I'm fairly new with ruby on rails.

Thanks

Comment: OK, I'll probably be switching from atom to vs code permanently after this headache. I was able to fix the issue after running the command in git bash using EDITOR="code.. instead of atom, something i hadn't yet tried. credentias.yml file saves after closing. still confused as to why I couldn't get this command to work in ubuntu... oh well, problem solved, moving on.

Comment: By "Windows 10 Ubuntu Linux" I take it you talking about the Windows Linux subsystem? WSL does not do great with compatibility with  programs like vi or emacs or the atom launcher. It tried it briefly and then switched to VirtualBox as there are just so many issues with wsl.